# Safari проблемы css анимации

Tags: html, css, mac, safari

Столкнулся с такой проблемой : при запуске анимации в macbook safari (только retina) пикселит цвет фона. Ссылку со скриншотом видео от заказчика прикреплю [Тут](https://prnt.sc/26fsvzj)
На старом маке, google chrome все в порядке. Так же фон сделан через background: #fff;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На маках с Retina возможен баг, из за которого анимации с использование transform scale могут пикселиться. Решение - использовать widht и heigth.